# How to quickly search for cases when a random walk intersects itself in R?

Tags: r, performance, geometry, vectorization, spatial

I have a time-stamped animal trajectory, and wish to ***quickly*** step through this trajectory, whilst looking a given time-interval backwards to identify when the animal  intersects its own path.

Suggestions regarding how to vectorize/parallelize the below would be gratefully received!

The input data is a 100000*6 matrix, 'traj', in which each row represents a straight-line segment (within a trajectory), built from two successive time-stamped coordinates (X1, Y1, T1 and X2, Y2, T2):

```
X1 <- runif(11)
Y1 <- runif(11)
T1 <- c(0.0, 0.5, 2.0, 3.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 12.0, 12.5, 13.0, 13.5)
X2 <- X1[2:11]
Y2 <- Y1[2:11]
T2 <- T1[2:11]
traj <- cbind(X1 = X1[1:10], Y1 = Y1[1:10], T1 = T1[1:10], X2, Y2, T2)
```

I define a function that converts two time-stamped coordinates to a `psp` line-segment (`spatstat`), and then uses `crossing.psp` (`spatstat`) to test if this segment intersects another line-segment. If so, the function writes the time difference between the two segments :

```
INTERSECTS <- function(x)  
{ 
  PastSeg <- psp(x["X1"], x["Y1"], x["X2"], x["Y2"], window = windy,  marks = x["T1"] , check = F)  ## A single line-segment, in which marks give times associated with the 2 coordinate pairs that define the segment
  Crossing <- crossing.psp(NowSeg,PastSeg)       ## Test if the 2 segments (PastSeg & NowSeg) intersect      
  if (Crossing$n > 0)
  {                                              ## print(paste("Crossing at ",x["T1"] ))
  out <-  cbind( NowSeg$marks, x["T1"],        ## Get the time of the current trajectory segment
                  NowSeg$marks - x["T1"],       ## Time elapsed between current segment, and past segment
                  Crossing$x, Crossing$y)
  write.table(out, file = "Crossings.txt", append = T, row.names = F, col.names = F)
  plot(Crossing, add = T)
  }
}
```

Last, I step segment-by-segment through 'traj'. At each step t, I consider a previous section of the trajectory `(t-*WINDOW*):(t-1)`, which is called *Past*, within which to apply *INTERSECTS* :

```
Window <- 3
library(spatstat)
windy <- owin()  
plot(windy,main="")
points(traj[,"X1"],traj[,"Y1"],type="l")

for(FR in 3: nrow(traj))  
 { 
 ## Define the current trajectory segment 
 NowSeg  <- psp(traj[FR,"X1"], traj[FR,"Y1"],
             traj[FR,"X2"], traj[FR,"Y2"],  
             marks=traj[FR,"T1"], check=F, window=windy)    ## The mark gives the time-stamp

 ## Extract coords up to WINDOW seconds in the past
 Past <- traj [traj[,"T1"] < traj[FR-1,"T1"] & traj[,"T1"] > (traj[FR,"T1"]-WINDOW),]  

 ## apply function over rows of Past, to successively test if each trajectory segment in PAST intersects with NowSeg
 if (!is.null(dim(Past))) { apply(Past, 1, INTERSECTS) }   
 }##FR
```

I have tried to replace this loop with an apply over the rows of *traj*, but did not succeed as *Past* requires indexing to a block of rows, not just a single row.

Comment: How fast does it have to be?

Comment: Well, a single trajectory can include 150 000 steps... so, faster than the above :-) Also, worth nothing that if the trajectory repeatedly revisits a given area, then *Past* gets long, so the speed depends on the amount of spatial recursion..

Comment: I would find all crossings first and then revisit each for the full test. I will have a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a partial answer, which is frowned upon in SO, but since it's been almost a day since you asked...

One way to proceed is to convert your trajectory into a `SpatialLines` object using package `sp`, then use `gIntersects(...)` in package `rgeos` to calculate all intersections of the trajectory with itself. This produces a logical n × n matrix, `M`, where `M[i,j] = TRUE` if the i<sup>th</sup> segment intersects with the j<sup>th</sup> segment. But there are three issues:

First, every line segment intersects with itself, so all the diagonal elements are `TRUE`; we have to set these to `FALSE`. Second, if `j>i` we are detecting an intersection between a segment and a future path, so we must set the lower triangle of the matrix to `FALSE`. Third, every line segment `j` by definition intersects with the following line segment, `j+1` because they have a point in common. So we have to set the elements `[j,j+1]` to `FALSE`.

```
n <- 10
set.seed(123)
X1 <- runif(n+1); Y1 <- runif(n+1)
T1 <- c(0.0,0.5,2.0,3.5,7.0,7.5,8.0,12.0,12.5,13.0,13.5)
# T1 <- 1:(n+1)
traj <- cbind(X1=X1[1:n],Y1=Y1[1:n],T1=T1[1:n],
              X2=X1[-1],Y2=Y1[-1],T2=T1[-1])

library(sp)
library(rgeos)
sp.lines <- SpatialLines(sapply(1:nrow(traj),
                         function(i)Lines(Line(rbind(traj[i,1:2],traj[i,4:5])),
                                          ID=i)))
M <- gIntersects(sp.lines,sp.lines,byid=TRUE)
diag(M)         <- FALSE
M[lower.tri(M)] <- FALSE
M[cbind(1:(nrow(traj)-1),2:nrow(traj))] <- FALSE
apply(M,2,any)
#     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10 
# FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE 
crossings <- traj[apply(M,2,any),"T1"]
crossings
# [1]  2  7  8 12 13

plot(sp.lines,col=1:n)
points(traj[,1],traj[,2],col="black",pch=c(as.character(1:9),"A"))
```

[image]

Now, for each column in `M`, if *any* of the rows are `TRUE` there is an intersection with some prior segment. The line

```
apply(M,2,any)
#     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10 
# FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

creates a logical vector with elements `TRUE` if that segment has an intersection with the existing path. So in the example segments 3, 5, 7, 8, and 10 had intersections with at least one earlier segment. If you compare this with the plot above, you'll see that is where the crossings occur.

We can use this vector as an index to the `T1` column of `traj` to identify the times when these intersections occurred.

```
crossings <- traj[apply(M,2,any),"T1"]
crossings
# [1]  2  7  8 12 13
```

So in this example there were crossings as T1 = 2, 7, 8, 12, 13.

Now here's the problem with this approach: For your full dataset, n ~ 1e5, so the matrix will have 1e10 (10 billion) elements. This is too large. Even if it wasn't, calculating the intersections for n = 1e4 takes about 3 minutes, and the process scales as O(n<sup>2</sup>), so with the full dataset it would take about 5 hours. This would be much faster than a loop, but still too slow.

If the segments are not too long, e.g. if the animal does not travel too far between points, you could sample the points. For instance,

```
smpl <- traj[seq(1,nrow(traj),by=10),]
```

will take every tenth row, and

```
smpl <- traj[sort(sample(1:nrow(traj),nrow(traj)/10)),]
```

will take a random sample of 10% of the points. If multiple random samples produce crossing times not significantly different from the evenly spaced sample, that's strong evidence that sampling is justified.